# How do you reach a certain value for two variables at the same time while iterating?

Tags: python, iteration

I have 2 variables that contain the amount of steps I want to do in each direction.

```
    # could be any values (including being the same amount)
    x_steps = 300
    y_steps = 200
```

Now I want to draw a line slowly by moving both the current x-coordinate and y-coordinate.
The important thing is, that I want to finish both directions at the same time, so it looks like a straight line.
This means, that in some iterations I need to do multiple steps for (in this case) x.

```
    for x in range(y_steps):
        # do step in y direction
        # do step in x direction
        if certain_condition:
            # do another step in x direction
```

I'm having trouble coming up with such a condition, how do I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by keeping track of the number of steps and using those numbers in the condition:

```py
i, j = 0, 0
for x in range(y_steps):
    # do step in y direction
    j += 1
    # do step in x direction
    i += 1
    if i/j < x_steps/y_steps:
        # do another step in x direction
        i += 1
```

To simplify this, you can use `x` (maybe rather call it `y`, as it runs through the y steps) directly instead of `j`, or use a `while` loop.